# Ajuda: Não consigo importa informações de uma URL para meu banco

Tags: mysqli

Senhores estou tentando coletar informações de uma URL e enviar para meu DB, na url a informações vem todos misturadas, com o scritp já consigo organizá-las da seguinte forma:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [PROTOCOLO] => 1234
        [FILA] => Rede
        [STATUS] => ABERTO
        [DT_ABERTURA] => 17/04/2018 16:10:34
        [SERVICO] => Registro de Falhas
        [REGIONAL] => EUA
        [LOCALIDADE] => IF
        [DESCRICAO] => Falha na placa 
        [INTERROMPEU] =>  
        [QNT_CLIENTE] => 0
        [OBS] => OG: 1234 [ABERTURA]
```

Porém não consigo coletar essas informações e lança-las no DB, preciso de ajuda. O mesmo no final da organização dos dados retorna o erro Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\teste.php on line 65.

A linha 65 é o mysqli_query("INSERT INTO

Segue meu código.

```
<?php



//function dados() {

$url = 'http://pordesemml.arecom.com.br/api/cor/teste.php?usuario=testes&senha=teste';

            $contents = file_get_contents($url);
            $contents = utf8_encode($contents);
            $results = json_decode($contents, true);
           echo "<pre>";
            print_r($results); 


            foreach ($results as $key => $value) { //$results é o conteudo que veio daquela url
            mysqli_connect (salvaBancoOG($value)); //ele pega cada linha armazena no $value e envia para uma função com o nome salvaBancoOG

            } 

      // }

 #Include do arquivo de configurações

function salvaBancoOG($value) {


    $data_registro = date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //data e hora atual
    $data_fim =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00";




     if ($value[PROTOCOLO] == null)
         $value[PROTOCOLO] = " ";
     if ($value[FILA] == null)
         $value[FILA] = " ";
     if ($value[STATUS] == null)
         $value[STATUS] = " ";
     if ($value[DT_ABERTURA] == null)
         $value[DT_ABERTURA] = " ";
     if ($value[SERVICO] == null)
         $value[SERVICO] = " ";
     if ($value[REGIONAL] == null)
         $value[REGIONAL] = " ";            
     if ($value[LOCALIDADE] == null)
         $value[LOCALIDADE] = " ";  
     if ($value[DESCRICAO] == null)
         $value[DESCRICAO] = " ";   
     if ($value[INTERROMPEU] == null)
         $value[INTERROMPEU] = " ";
     if ($value[QNT_CLIENTE] == null)
         $value[QNT_CLIENTE] = " ";         
     if ($value[OBS] == null)
         $value[OBS] = " "; 


 }      

         mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 'diario' (`protocolo`, `fila`, `status`, `dt_abertura`, `servico`, `regional`, `localidade`, `descricao`, `massiva`, `qnt_cliente`, `obs`, `id`) 
         VALUES  ('12345678','Tx','Em Aberto','2018-04-17 00:00:00','ula','ula','escrição teste','1','10','deletar','''','''','''','''','NULL');"); //envia para o banco de dados



?>
```

A minha conexão com o Banco é através de uma variável:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect($local_serve, $usuario_serve, $senha_serve, $banco_de_dados) or die ("O servidor não responde!");
```

Comment: Não coloque a imagem do código. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código por escrito, de um Ctrl+V na sua pergunta. Imagens não ajudam muito nesse caso

Comment: Olá, Rodrigo! Seja bem-vindo. Conforme dito pelo @hugocwl, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código. Infelizmente imagens são mais difíceis de ler e a busca do SO e do Google não consegue indexar o código dentro dela.